# java.net.ConnectException: Call From wwt/127.0.1.1 to localhost:34579 failed on connection exception:

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.3.jar wordcount /wcinput /wcoutput
```

Result:

```
FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1684829896790_0001_01_000002 : java.net.ConnectException: Call From wwt/127.0.1.1 to localhost:34579 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Comment: YARN is working fine. It launched a container and returned you an error. 1) Read the link in the error 2) Open the YARN UI and find why your app failed. Also re-read the hadoop installation docs that mentioned to remove `127.0.1.1` lines from your /etc/hosts files